# JavaScript - find all elements with class, find duplicates and show them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find all duplicates on the current page, count them and make a list which how many duplicates are there. So far I have this code, but it is only showing how many elements are on the page. What am I doing wrong?

I am getting div elements, and I am trying to make a list which div elements are duplicated, how many times and to show whole code structure `<div>text<span>text</span></div>`

The duplicate element can be something like this:

```
<div>this is the <span>text</span> with <strong>something</strong></div>
```

I need to find if this whole **div element** is on the page more than once, and make list like this:

```
<div>this is the <span>text</span> with <strong>something</strong></div> - count(2)
```

Code so far:

```
let htmlCollectionArray = document.getElementsByClassName('sql-hl-main')
let  count = {}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(htmlCollectionArray, function(el, i) { 
    count[el] = (count[el]||0) + 1;
});
```

Comment: What is a unique element? `el` is always unique. Are you counting tags (div, p, etc...)?

Comment: I am getting **div elements**, and I am trying to make a list which **div elements** are duplicated, how many times and to show whole code structure `<div>text<span>text</span></div>`

Comment: So duplicated is the outer html (div + it's content) string?

Comment: @Sasha, still is not clear what you mean under "duplicated"... Element is always unique, it can not be duplicated... Duplicated cam be text or class or some attribute but "elements are duplicated" is nonsence

Comment: Show us an example

Comment: @OriDrori please check the edit.

Comment: The `.sql-hl-main` class is the parent of all the div elements?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou yep, this is the parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all div elements under a class name (`.sql-hl-main div`), and it returns a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Iterate the NodeList with [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and use the elements' [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) string as the key:

```js
const count = {};
document.querySelectorAll('.sql-hl-main div')
  .forEach(el => {
    const key = el.outerHTML; // or innerHTML if you don't want the container div
    count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
  });

console.log(count)
```

```html
<div class="sql-hl-main">
  <div>this is the <span>text</span> with <strong>something</strong></div>
  <div>text<span>text</span></div>
  <div>this is the <span>text</span> with <strong>something</strong></div>
  <div>this is the <span>text</span> with <strong>something</strong></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean `count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1`;

Comment: The value of `count[key]` (`{ '<div>...</div': 1 }`) is the current value `count[key]` (1 in this example) or 0 if the value is falsy (`undefined` or 0 in this case) plus 1. So the result of this expression in this example would be `{ '<div>...</div': 2 }`. The key is the outerHTML string of the object (`<div>...</div>`).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the length property?

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('sql-hl-main').length);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('sql-h3-main').length);
```

```html
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-hl-main"></div>
<div class="sql-h3-main"></div>
<div class="sql-h3-main"></div>
```